# How to get only lowercase strings from a list using list comprehension

Tags: python

The question asked:

Use list comprehensions to generate a list with only the lowercase letters in my_list. Print the result list.

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D']
```

My code:

```
my_list = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D']
hi = ([ char for char in range(len(my_list)) if char%2 == 0])

print(hi)
```

I tried it out, but got integers as answers and not the strings I wanted.

Comment: I edited the title of this question as it was misleading and did not match the question's content

Comment: What were you trying to solve with the code snippet you shared? What it does has nothing to do with what you're asking for

Comment: You are looping over a `range` object, so why did you expect for `char` to be anything other than `int` objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python strings have `islower` method. Also, you can directly iterate over the list, no need to check its length or the parity of the indexes.

```
my_list = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D']
hi = [char for char in my_list if char.islower()]
print(hi)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', d']
```

Answer (score 6):

Note: several answers here assume that what you want is to select the values in the list that are lowercase. This answer assumes that that was an *example* and that the thing you're trying to do is to select the values in the list that occur at every other list index. (This seems to me to be the correct interpretation, because that's what the implementation in the question appears to be *trying* to do.) I'm not sure who misunderstood the question here, but since the question can be interpreted multiple ways, I think the question is probably at fault here. Until the question is clarified, I think it should be placed on hold.

The simplest and fastest way to do this is with a slice:

```
print(my_list[::2])  # Slice the whole list, with step=2
```

To replicate the logic you're describing, where you want to take the values with *indexes* that are modulo 2, then you need to generate both the indexes and the values for your list in the comprehension, and use one for the filtering and the other for the result:

```
hi = [ch for ix, ch in enumerate(my_list) if ix % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your list comprehension:

```
[char for char in range(len(my_list)) if char%2 == 0]
```

Will produce integers instead of characters. This is because `range(len(my_list))` gives you indices. You instead need to get the characters.

This can be done using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
 [char for i, char in enumerate(my_list) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Or a less pythonic approach, using just indexing `my_list`:

```
[my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list)) if i % 2 == 0]
```

You can also just filter out the lowercase letters with [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower):

```
[char for char in my_list if char.islower()]
```

Which avoids having to use indices altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension as following where you iterate over your individual elements and check if it is a lower case using `.islower()`

```
my_list = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D']

lower = [i for i in my_list if i.islower()]
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D']
res = [ char for char in  my_list if ord(char)>=97]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `islower()` function

```
l = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D']
result = [el for el in l if el.islower()]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a range(len(my_list)) that create the following range(0, 8)
and char, in this case, is an integer and you create a list of integers.

To generate a list with only the lowercase letters use 'islower' method
hi = ([ char for char in my_list if char.islower()])